# $7^n+5*7^m$ and $2*7^n+4*7^m$ are divisible by 3

Tags: divisibility

While I was helping my daughter with some advanced task from homework, we came to assumption in title.
Experiment shows that it is most likely true.
But I can't came up with formal proof.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

*Hint:* $7 = 1 + 2\cdot3$.${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 3):

Notice that $7\equiv 1 \mod 3$ so the two expressions  are $\equiv 0\mod 3$ so your guess is true.

Answer (score 1):

If you know Binomial Expansion then you can expand $7^n$ and $7^m$ using:$$7^n=(1+6)^n$$
$$7^m=(1+6)^m$$
to get the desired result.